# PHP new array from old array

Tags: php

Here is the code in question:

```
$countries = array("New Zealand", "Australia", "United Kingdom", "New Zealand");
```

I am after some code that will let me declare a new array from this previous array with me specifying how many items in the array.

eg:

If I did something like this:

```
$newArray = $countries[1], $newArray will hold "New Zealand" and "Australia"
$newArray = $countries[2], $newArray will hold "New Zealand", "Australia" and "United Kingdom"
```

Currently I am doing this by using a for loop. Is there an easier/more efficient way to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`array_slice()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
$array1 = array_slice($input, 0, 2);
$array2 = array_slice($input, 0, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

array_slice() is what you're looking for:

```
$countries = array("New Zealand", "Australia", "United Kingdom", "New Zealand");
$length = 3;
$newArray = array_slice($countries, 0, $length);
// $newArray == array("New Zealand", "Australia", "United Kingdom")
```

http://php.net/array_slice

Answer (score 0):

you can use [array_slice](http://www.php.net/array_slice) to extract it